# How can I show more than 1 row in responsive view of Datatables.net?

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatables

This is my table in desktop mode :
[image]

In responsive or mobile view ,only user can view country name without click on + button at now,but I want to show (name,buy price,sell price) without click on + button and when user clicked on + button show the user other columns (date,chart,country name). 
 
how can i do this with tables of datatables.net?

Answer (score 0):

Doc:

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/columnPriority.html

So, you have to use `responsivePriority` in `columnDefs` propertly in your DataTable constructor:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 1 }, // name
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 2 }, // buy price
            { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 3 }, // sell price
            { responsivePriority: 4, targets: 0 },
            { responsivePriority: 5, targets: 4 },
            { responsivePriority: 6, targets: 5 }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

**EDIT**:

Ok, this is more complicated so... First, use this for `fixed columns`: [How to fixed the last column of a responsive DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109023/how-to-fixed-the-last-column-of-a-responsive-datatable) and then use `row_details` plugin (you have to fill de data inside each row by iterating the current row): https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: Hi @Dani I know this , But I have told i want to show (name,buy price,sell price) to show when my site is showing on mobile devices , at now only country name shows on mobile devices and if i want to show more i should click on + button , but i want to show that 3 columns on default and if users wants to see more click on +  button, see this image : (name,buy price,sell price)>>bit.ly/31J6h8e